# Get only the first child of every td in a row in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, each

So example I have this kind of table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1">         <!-- FIND only this element -->
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2        <!-- FIND only this text and disregard checkbox input-->
         <checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am making a `.each()` function which would only get the values of every first element of every `td` per row.

I have tried 
`$(this).find('tr td:first-child').each()` function but I know that this would only get the first `td` of every row and it would not go through every `td` which is I want.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have edited the comment inside the code to be more precise. It should not really be surrounded with a div, I just want the first value of anything inside of a    `td`  tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<table border="1" class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First</span>
      <span>Second</span>
      <span>Third</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>First</span>
      <span>Second</span>
      <span>Third</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

    //jQuery code
    $('.myTable tr td').each(function() {

        //First child of td
      $(this).children(':first').css('color', 'red');

    });
```

Here is the [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dkyqs19e/1/)

If you just need the text of the first element then you can do so by using the [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function

```
$('.myTable tr td').each(function() {

  //First child of td
  var firstChild = $(this).children(':first');
  alert(firstChild.text());

});
```

Comment: `.children()` does not return text nodes.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc we can save the child element and call the `text()` function to get the text. Please see my edit.

Comment: getting the children was the most applicable for my scenario. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want the first value of anything inside `td` tag including text node so you can try to use [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) or [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

Example:

```js
$('table tr td').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).contents()[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1">         <!-- FIND only this element -->
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2        <!-- FIND only this text and disregard checkbox input-->
         <checkbox></checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or without jquery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr td').forEach(function(td) {
  console.log(td.childNodes[0]);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1">         <!-- FIND only this element -->
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2        <!-- FIND only this text and disregard checkbox input-->
         <checkbox></checkbox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table tr td').each(function() {

 //First child of td
  $(this).children(':first').css('border-color', 'red'); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1" value="name">         <!-- FIND only this element -->
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2  <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1">  
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2  
        <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1">        
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2 <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input textbox text="test1" value="name"> 
        <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>test2 <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope so this will helpful for you